# Obtaining a NIE in Spain ! (Foreigners Identity Card)

Tags: residency, spain

To transact any Business in Spain as a Non-Resident you need a ‘Foreigners Identity Card’ or a NIE.

To obtain this - on the Application Form EX-15 asks for proof that you intend to transact Business in Spain. It occurred to me that with Confirmation of having a REVOLUT account could be presented as proof. As it can be used in Spain & has a Swift payment facility ! But has anyone tried this & will it be excepted at the Spanish Consulate in the UK ! Someone may be able to answer this ! I don’t know ! But no harm in asking ! Thanks !

Comment: I suspect that proving intention to transact would require more than just having an account through which payments can be made. What type of business - sole trader, limited company? Contracts with clients? Import/export licence?